# angularjs ngHide ngShow reversed in IE

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some angularjs `ngHide` and `ngShow` code.  They work fine in Chrome but show the opposite in IE.  The following is what the code looks like:

```
 <section ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div class="details" ng-show="showDetails">
         Section 1
     </div>

     <div class="move-details" ng-hide="showDetails">
         Section 2
     </div>
 </section>
```

JS File:

```
var ctrl = ['$scope', 'model', function($scope, model) {
     $scope.showDetails = true;
}];
```

The text with `Section 2` is shown instead of `Section 1` in IE but `Section 1` is shown in Chrome like I would expect.

Am I just missing something?

Comment: You are closing a `)` instead of a `]` in the end. And the "Hidden" text show be visible if `showDetails` is true, not the "Shown" one.

Comment: That was a typo sorry

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, Can yo create a fiddle or plnkr, Its working fine for me see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EnrHx83RuZSm0Uhxsg4m?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Switching from `<section>` to a `<div>` tag resolved the problem.

Comment: Likely because older IE doesn't support HTML5 elements like section  without shims.